Should a npm run build produce an about.html file for a React application which has an about page?
I have built a React application which is producing an Error 404 page not found exception when deployed to a production system. It is deployed in production behind nginx.
When I run it locally with npm run dev, everything behaves as expected. Because there are a number of moving parts, I am not sure where the problem is.
As a first step, I would like to ask whether the build output is normal.
I have run the build using npm run build. The dist folder contains the following files:
dist/assets/index-DLJ2hglj.js
dist/assets/react-CHdo91hT.svg
dist/index.html
dist/vite.svg

It does not contain dist/about.html. I do not know if this is expected.
I have defined an About page. Here is the AboutPage.jsx file:
import React from 'react';
import { Typography } from '@mui/material';

export default function AboutPage() {
  return (
    <>
      <Typography>
        About page
      </Typography>
    </>
  );
}

I use it from router.jsx:
import React from 'react';

import { createBrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

import AboutPage from './routes/AboutPage';
import NotFoundPage from './routes/NotFoundPage';
import RootPage from './routes/RootPage';
import MainPage from './routes/MainPage';

export const router = createBrowserRouter([
  { path: '/', element: <RootPage></RootPage> },
  { path: '/mainpage', element: <MainPage></MainPage> },
  { path: '/about', element: <AboutPage></AboutPage> },
  {
    path: '*',
    element: <NotFoundPage></NotFoundPage>,
  },
]);

FYI the RootPage just contains a useEffect hook which causes a redirect to /mainpage.
The router is used from main.jsx:
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import { router } from './router'
import { RouterProvider } from 'react-router-dom';
import { ThemeProvider } from '@mui/material';
import { CssBaseline } from '@mui/material';
import { globalTheme } from './globalTheme';

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <ThemeProvider theme={globalTheme}>
      <CssBaseline />
      <RouterProvider router={router} />
    </ThemeProvider>
  </React.StrictMode>
);

When I test this locally (npm run dev), everything works as expected:

Browser url: http://localhost:5173/ -> goes to MainPage
Browser url: http://localhost:5173/mainpage -> goes to MainPage
Browser url: http://localhost:5173/about -> goes to AboutPage

When I build the application with npm run build and copy the dist folder to the production server, it starts to behave strangely:

Browser url: www.example.com/ -> takes me to the MainPage
Browser url: www.example.com/mainpage -> 404 not found (Nginx 404 page)
Browser url: www.example.com/about -> 404 not found (Nginx 404 page)

The dist folder does not have an about.html page. Is this normal? Knowing the answer to this will tell me whether or not I need to ask further questions about the Nginx configuration.

Are you intending to do any server-side rendering? Looks like you have a single-page app, all the routing happens on the client side.

@jonrsharpe I don't believe so, the application makes some requests to a backend, and then populates some tables. So I think this is a static site with client side logic to retreive data which the client then inserts into the relevant tables.

This question is similar to: Nginx - config to route to single page app. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

See also various guidance on https://vitejs.dev/guide/static-deploy

@jonrsharpe I can't ask more than one question at once - so that's why I've asked first about whether the build should produce an about.html (or similar)

I don't believe it is similar to that question - the author is asking how to remap the address .../first-website to .../

The question as posed is useless, to you and SO - you're asking what a command you do not show should do. The short answer is "no", using information from your various other questions indicating use of Vite, but what help is that to your 404 problem?! You need to 1. know what you're trying to build (a single page app, where the "routing" all happens on the client); and 2. configure your server accordingly (rewrites, shown in dupe, or pick another - https://stackoverflow.com/q/43951720/3001761, https://stackoverflow.com/q/74982873/3001761, ...).

I do show the command: npm run build. It's right there at the top

This should be a very standard thing. You build an application with React. You use React Router to enable having multiple pages. You build each page as a React Component. Then you build it. Should the build generate a single index.html or should it generate one html file per route?

"I do show the command: npm run build" Should this npm run build produce an about.html file? What about this one? This one? "Should the build generate a single index.html or should it generate one html file per route?" - again, are you intending to server-side render? Please read up on SPAs.

@jonrsharpe Are you asking me to provide the package.json file? I have absolutly no idea what you're trying to ask here

No clue what this guy is trying to say

The answer to this question is "Yes". (At least assuming default setup for Vite - I don't know maybe it can be configured to behave differently or something as implied by @jonrsharpe comments above.)
Here's the point:

Yes, it should build a single index.html page. No about.html page, etc.
Nginx does not know what /about is or where it is, because about.html does not exist
This is why Nginx is reporting error 404 when the React app is deployed behind it


As a bonus, here's how to fix the Nginx server block.
        location / {
                try_files $uri /index.html =404;
        }

The key bit which was missing before is the presence of /index.html.
I could have asked a whole seperate question to add this detail in an answer but it seemed a bit pointless.
